# Create multiple empty files whose names will be obtained from the file

Tags: bash

I want to create empty files where the names are taken from list.txt. I tried this:

```
declare -a siglist=$(cat list.txt)

for fname in {list}; do 
    echo $fname > "$fname.zz"
done
```

Comment: `touch $(sed 's/$/.zz/' list.txt)`

Comment: `xargs -I {} touch {}.zz < list.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Note that your `echo` solution does *not* create empty files: they contain a single newline.

If you want to stay entirely in the shell (the comments show various ways using touch and xargs), you can use the *null-command* `:` (which does nothing) with a redirection as follows.

```
while read filename; do
    : > "${filename}.zz"
done < list.txt
```

This is portable to all Bourne-heritage shells, so not restricted to bash.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with `awk`, could you please try following.

```
awk '{val=(val?val OFS:"")$0} END{system("touch " val)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Creating a variable named `val` in `awk` program and keep concatenating line's values into it. In `END` section of this `awk` program using `system` command of this command to use `touch` command and passing that variable `val` to it to create all file names there.

Comment: @Gamarlinsky, could you please do let me know if this answer has helped you?